# document.addEventListener fails to work sometimes

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have `document.addEventListener` attached to several elements. Then there is a page having several elements sharing the same class named xxxx and I get which element of class xxxx was clicked using the code below:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target.className === 'xxxx') {
        //something happens
    }
);
```

The problem is that it works in some cases and fails to work in some cases. Whenever it doesn't work and I click on a random area of the same element it works again. I would like to know what could be the problem.

Comment: You have to add a [mre] for that. Most likely cause is that you aren't clicking the element but a child of it or the like.

Comment: Chris, your reply is correct regarding a child element taking up space and preventing the parent element from receiving the click event. Thank you for the comment. So how do I ensure the parent element always receives the click event and not the child element?

Comment: Here's one way, using a custom function that walks up the tree: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/08ous6ew/ (this also addresses chofre's comment)

Comment: @Chris G, I added this line: `pointer-events: none` to the CSS style of the child element and it solved the problem. Thanks for your comment once again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the elements that don't respond have several different class names.

```
event.target.className === 'xxxx'
```

is an exact string comparator, and if the element has several class names, e.g. 'xxxx yyyy', the === comparator will return 'false'.
Try

```
event.target.classList.contains('xxxx')
```

Explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList